# Solaris prstat - definition of "recent" time used in percentages

Tags: performance, unix, cpu, monitoring, solaris

The man page for prstat (on Solaris 10 in my case) notes that that CPU % output is the "percentage of *recent* CPU time". I am trying to understand in more depth what "recent" means in this context - is it a defined amount of time prior to the sample, does it relate to the sampling interval, etc? Appreciate any insights, particularly with references to supporting documentation. I've searched but haven't been able to find a good answer. Thanks!

- Adrian

Answer (score 2):

The kernel maintains data that you see at the bottom - those three numbers.
For each process.

`uptime` shows you what those numbers are.  Those are the 'recent' times for load average - the line at the bottom of `prstat`.  1 minute,  5 minutes, and 15 minutes.

Recent == 1 minute worth of  sampling (last 60 seconds).  Those numbers are averages, which is why when you first start `prstat` the number and processes usually change.

On the first pass you may see processes like nscd  that have lots of cpu but have been up for a long time.  The first display iteration is completely historical.  After that the numbers reflect recent == last one minute average.

You should consider enabling sar sampling to get a much better picture.

Want a reference  - try :

[http://www.amazon.com/Solaris-Internals-OpenSolaris-Architecture-Edition/dp/0131482092](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131482092)